# Need multiple independent timers in Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, timer, stopwatch

I need the ability to create up to N amount timers in JavaScript/Ajax that will count like a stopwatch(but have no buttons).

Another issue is that my data will be loaded via another Ajax request so the page will constantly be updating. I'm not sure how I would be able to keep a timer's correct value when that happens.

Thanks!

Comment: You should check out the JavaScript `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions.

Comment: I know about those functions. The issue I'm having is in having multiple timers. I don't know the quantity beforehand. I've tried setting time with those two but it doesn't sync well.

Comment: @James, so create a structure on the backend ( JSON comes to mind ), and loop through it on the client, thereby creating as many timeouts or intervals as you may need.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript already has this functionality.  Checkout the

```
setInterval
setTimeout
```

functions.  Both will let you say "In x number of milliseconds, I want the following callback function to fire".  With `setTimeout`, the callback fires once.  With `setInterval`, the callback fires repeatedly until you tell it to stop.